# Passing string into bash script

Tags: sql, bash

I have this script which dumps a db:

```
cat /usr/bin/dbbkup
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uroot -proot db > db_$(date +%d%H%M%S).sql
```

Which I execute like so:

```
dbbkup && ls -atlr
```

But how can I pass an argument into this script that will prefix the db dump? E.G.

```
dbbkup -arg "changed name of field" && ls -atlr
```

Then change the script to something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uroot -proot db > db_$(arg)_$(date +%d%H%M%S).sql
```

Thanks =)

Comment: I've tried what I have above. I am no expert in Bash, hence why I am seeking help from professionals on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash scripts reference parameters in order, e.g.:

```
dbbkup "changed name of field"
```

becomes the variable `$1` in your script.

So to continue your example, to create a db dump with a custom filename based on date and with a certain prefix, your command would be:

```
./dbbkup.sh prefix
```

and the contents of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uroot -proot db > db_$1_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).sql
```

This will produce a file called `db_prefix_20120919104317.sql`. I changed the date format, as you have more information, and in a directory listing you can now sort by name and also have them sorted by time.

Also, I'm assuming you want this as an example of how to use bash parameters, as the parameter you are passing in has no bearing on the output created, just the filename, in which case why not hardcode the name of the file? I don't see the use case for files with multiple names with the same (albeit updated) data.

Comment: If the script needs to be able to handle spaces in the argument (like "changed name of field"), you need to put double-quotes around all uses of it: `mysqldump -uroot -proot db > "db_$1_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).sql"`

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point. I don't like spaces in file names so removed them for the actual example, but I can see how the initial parameter could confuse someone else coming along. Thank's for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter handed to the bash script will be $1.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uroot -proot db > $1db_$(date +%d%H%M%S).sql
```

call it like this:

```
dbbkup prefix
```